# how to interact with Paramiko's interactive shell session?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have some Paramiko code where I use the invoke_shell method to request an interactive ssh shell session on a remote server. Method is outlined here: [invoke_shell()](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.invoke_shell)

Here's a summary of the pertinent code:

```
sshClient = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshClient.connect('127.0.0.1', username='matt', password='password')
channel = sshClient.get_transport().open_session()
channel.get_pty()
channel.invoke_shell()

while True:
    command = raw_input('$ ')
    if command == 'exit':
        break

    channel.send(command + "\n")

    while True:
        if channel.recv_ready():
            output = channel.recv(1024)
            print output
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if not(channel.recv_ready()):
                break

sshClient.close()
```

My question is: is there a better way to interact with the shell? The above works, but it's ugly with the two prompts (the matt@kali:~$ and the $ from raw_input), as shown in the screenshot of a test run with the interactive shell. I guess I need help writing to the stdin for the shell? Sorry, I don't code much. Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: Thanks @whjm. No purpose other than just writing an SSH client for fun. I would prefer to stick with Paramiko.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imported a file, [interactive.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/interactive.py), found on Paramiko's GitHub. After importing it, I just had to change my code to this:

```
try:
    import interactive
except ImportError:
    from . import interactive

...
...

channel.invoke_shell()
interactive.interactive_shell(channel)
sshClient.close()
```

Comment: on windows: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`. Line 87 in `interactive.py` should be changed to: `sys.stdout.write(data.decode("utf8", "ignore"))`

Comment: I had some issues with control character and line wrapping causing unexpected behaviour with zsh autocompletion.

I've modified the demo to support this here: https://gist.github.com/mvanderlee/c6fb0bf7611565e43813bfa503f2afc1

Answer (score 3):

You can try disabling *echo* after invoking the remote shell:

```
channel.invoke_shell()
channel.send("stty -echo\n")

while True:
    command = raw_input() # no need for `$ ' anymore
    ... ...
```